# Clickable area on button is too small

Tags: html, css, button

So I was experimenting with a new type of button, using a tutorial I cannot find now...and the end product WORKS but the clickable area on the button is extremely frustrating, small. I've tried editing the css since I think this is just a css issue but I cannot get it to work. Because of the small clickable area it seems to not work on a mobile device.

The website in question is http://forrestburdette.com/
The button in question is the top right button for their Children's Outreach Ministries. It seems to only be clickable on the far right middle of the button. I need some guidance on where I went wrong! Hoping this is an easy fix!!!

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a link to an example, if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: So sorry for that. I'll make it a priority to make sure I always include the code. Thanks for the reminder Paulie_D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently the button is underneath the header which is why the link is being cut off. To solve this you need to add a `z-index` to the `div` containing the button, like so:

```
.forrest_burdette_childrens_outreach_button {
  position: absolute;
  top: -9px;
  right: -1px;
  width: 220px;
  height: 52px;
  z-index: 1; /* add z-index */
}
```

This will bring the button above the header, allowing the full width of the link to be clickable

Comment: Totally worked...and I totally would have never guessed the z-index!